# there are 2 indices Employee{ Name, Age, I'd,} Account{ I'd Pay} . there are duplicates data name and pay. the solution to find out the duplicates.?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-6

What if there are 2 indices in elastic search.

Employee{ Name, Age, I'd,}
Account{ I'd Pay}

And there are duplicates data like name and pay. What will be the solution to find out the duplicates.

Thanks in advance

Complete query in kibana

Comment: The duplicates are within one index or across the two indices? This question should generally have a small test-set with a handful of sample documents — otherwise it will be just guesswork

Comment: Duplicates are in the both indexed

Comment: If you only want to find duplicates, you might just run a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the keyword of the fields where you don't want to have duplicates?